# Systemtap PPC32 support

Tags: linux, debugging, linux-kernel, systemtap

Does Systemtap have PPC32 support ? I see it is mentioned it is supported in Intel and PPC64 platforms but there is not much information about PPC32.

Also, can SystemTap used to debug customized loadable kernel modules ?

Thanks,
Sethu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Systemtap has only ppc64 support anymore.

You can find ppc-32 support if you use "Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5 server", or other older distributions.

If you are thinking of using any other similar tools, here is a comparison list:

http://sourceware.org/systemtap/wiki/SystemtapDtraceComparison

Answer (score 0):

Systemtap also supports the PPC64LE architecture, that is basically the new ABI for PPC64 and run in little endian mode.

```
brenohl@sid:~/stap$ apt-cache show systemtap
Package: systemtap
Priority: optional
Section: universe/devel
Installed-Size: 3066
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Ritesh Raj Sarraf <rrs@debian.org>
Architecture: ppc64el
```